# Add Client Log in area to Kirby

Tags: kirby

I'm pretty new to Kirby, trying to build my first site with it, and the site is for a photographer who wants clients to be able to log in where they can view and download their photos. Is that something I could do with Kirby? I saw this - http://getkirby.com/blog/frontend-authentication  - but it was a while ago, and I didn't see any plugins listed on their current plugin list that seemed to fit what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://getkirby.com/docs/solutions/authentication.
You may update your Kirby root.